# Need static IP from home (currently using Comcast home service)

Tags: internet, static-ip

I have a remote server (non-Comcast) which I wish to give access to only from my home which uses Comcast.

To do so, I need to configure my remote server to only accept access from my home IP.  As such, I don't wish my home IP to change.

What are my options?

Comment: Another option is using Dynamic DNS services such as http://www.noip.com/ I've used them to establish VPN networks before so am aware that they are capable of being 'quick enough' to work in the type of situation that you are asking of them.

Comment: @dtbnguyen  I will probably go down this route.  Please feel free to leave this as an answer as it effectively gives me a static IP.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is using Dynamic DNS services such as noip.com I've used them to establish VPN networks before so am aware that they are capable of being 'quick enough' to work in the type of situation that you are asking of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on limiting access based on IP you will have to sign a contract with your ISP that includes a fixed IP address.

Alternative methods for limiting access might be cheaper and easier to set up.

Comment: I just talked (or chatted) with Comcast.  The guy said he changed my service to not change the IP, but he also said not to reset my router, so I think maybe he didn't do anything.  What are other alternative methods?

Comment: @user10 - There isn't an alternative to what you want.  If you want to do exactly what you described that only way to do that is for Comcast to assign you a static ip address which won't be **free**.